# Making one of the column dividers thicker than the others in a browse

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a browse with **5** columns. I want the dividing line between columns **3** and **4** to be a little thicker.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no, you can't change the line between columns.

But you could add an empty dummy column with blank values between column 3 and 4, that you could get to look it like a thicker separator.

Regards,